# Formatting a table in Prolog

Tags: formatting, prolog

I am trying to print out a table of values in Prolog. Currently I have the following:

```
format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []).
format('|~tTable Title~t~78||~n', []),
format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []).
```

Produces my header:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|                                 Table Title                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to pad some columns to produce the following format beneath

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Name                 | Age      | Eye Colour        | Phone Number          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Joe Bloggs           | 21       | Blue              | 01234567890           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| John Smith           | 32       | Brown             | (+44) 012345678       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried multiple methods of spreading the columns evenly. However this code:

```
format('| ~s~t~28|| ~s~t~8|| ~s~t~20|| ~s~t~24||~n', 
                              ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye Colour', 'Phone Number']).
```

Gives me uneven columns which aren't nicely spaced.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Name                      | Age| Eye Colour| Phone Number|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The documentation on this was slightly confusing and I don't seem to be able to get my head round it so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab spacing refers to *absolute* columns: try

```
format('| ~s~t~28|| ~s~t~36|| ~s~t~56|| ~s~t~80||~n',
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do relative colums with `~+`:

```
?- format('| ~s~t~28|| ~s~t~8+| ~s~t~20+| ~s~t~24+|~n', 
                              ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye Colour', 'Phone Number']).
| Name                      | Age   | Eye Colour        | Phone Number          |
true.
```